# Android Studio Not Importing AppCompat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I am not sure what I did, but all of the sudden Android Studio cannot import the AppCompat theme, it has created several compile time errors and referencing a specific jar:

[image]

[image]

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.3'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: It said missing recyclerview-v7.jar. Try to add, `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'` in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Please copy and paste error message rather than posting screenshots.

Comment: Also try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: Make sure to update both "Android Support Repository" and "Android Support Library" in SDK Manager